# Как  установить Flash Player на Linux /GNU Debian?

Tags: flash-player, debian

Загрузила Linux/GNU Debian и не могу Flash Player установить. Скачивала в интернете, но ни один не запустился. Ошибку выдает. Помогите, мэйби что-то не доустановила я.

Answer (score 2):

В терминале:

```
aptitude install flashplugin-nonfree
```

или для скачаного файла:

```
dpkg -i имя пакета.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Система -> Администрирование -> Программа управления пакетами Synaptic, попросит пароль, введите пароль пользователя root. В появившемся окне введите в поиск flash. В списке найденных пакетов выберите flashplugin-nonfree и отметьте его для установки, ну и нажмите кнопочку с галочкой (установить)

Правка от 11 Января 2016:
flashpugin-nonfree более не действителен. Используйте flashplugin-installer

Comment: flashplugin-installer - его нет в списках и нет в результатах поиска через терминал командой `sudo aptitude search flash`

Answer (score 0):

Установка в Ручную

Скачиваете [flashplayer tar.gz](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/26.0.0.131/flash_player_npapi_linux.x86_64.tar.gz) 
Распаковываете в /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree (если папки нету создайте).

Вводите команды (с правами суперпользователя):

```
chmod 644 /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
chown root:root и /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
```

Проверяете альтернативные варианты плеера:

```
update-alternatives --list flash-mozilla.so
```

Если нет альтернатив, то вводите: `update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flash-mozilla.so flash-mozilla.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so 50`